# What's the best way to use the truthiness of a JS value in Scala.js?

Tags: null, undefined, scala.js

In JavaScript, it's quite easy (and legible) to write things like

```
var a = getString(); // say, some string, possibly null or undefined
var b = fallback(); // fallback value
var c = a || b;
```

In Scala.js, can I do better than this to have the same semantics?

```
val a: UndefOr[String] = getString()
val b: String = fallback()
val c = a.filter(_ != null).getOrElse(b)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Truthiness in JS is tricky. For example, the empty string is just as much falsy as `null` and `undefined`. Your two examples are therefore not equivalent. According to your description, I expect the second one to be more correct wrt. your requirements, kind of proving the point that truthiness is dangerous.

Your second snippet is nice. If you are really interfacing with a library that uses `null` *and* `undefined` as empty (which is already suspicious, even for JS; usually it will be one *or* the other, but not both), then I would suggest that you define a small helper function:

```scala
def fromJSWithNullOrUndefined[A](x: js.UndefOr[A]): Option[A] =
  x.toOption.filter(_ != null)
```

which encodes once and for all the idiosyncratic behavior that both `null` and `undefined` should map to `None`, and then use it as follows:

```scala
val c = fromJSWithNullOrUndefined(getString()).getOrElse(fallback())
```

Scala developers will find this much more readable than the `||` code in the beginning. It is much more idiomatic.